# Constructing Array of IDs from loops in ListView Adapter android

Tags: java, android, android-listview

The image below is my listview with row item checkbox

[image]

when i select checkbox @row 1:

the id of that image is printed out using the loop below

```
final CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) row
                .findViewById(R.id.cbBox);
        cb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                if (infodata.get(position).isclicked) {
                    infodata.get(position).isclicked = false;
                } else {
                    infodata.get(position).isclicked = true;
                }

                for(int i=0;i<infodata.size();i++)
                {
                    if (infodata.get(i).isclicked) {

                        System.out.println("Selectes Are == "+data.get(i).getId());

                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

when i click on first checkbox result is:

Selectes Are == 1000000062

second checkbox click result are:

Selectes Are == 1000000062
Selectes Are == 1000000095

third checkbox click result are:

Selectes Are == 1000000062
Selectes Are == 1000000095
Selectes Are == 1000000058

Note that after each checkbox click it click all infodata selected again.

How can i stored selected values resulted from System.out.println("Selectes Are == "+data.get(i).getId()); into an array for e.g. [1000000062,1000000095,1000000058]

Comment: Add onclick code here? You can do it by using arrayList..

Comment: i updated the question with the checkbox onclicklistener

Comment: What is purpose of `infodata.get(position).isclicked` check and setting to false?

Comment: May be you can perform these operations on a separate button click after all the selection is done.

Comment: yes but how to track selected click items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create and empty ArrayList outside of the onClick() method.

Use this code:

```
if (infodata.get(position).isclicked) {
   infodata.get(position).isclicked = false;
   //Remove it if you want to
   //arrayList.remove(data.get(i).getId());
} else {
   infodata.get(position).isclicked = true;
   arrayList.add(data.get(i).getId());
}
```

You can remove the for loop as it may not be needed.

Edited:

In the end put for loop:

```
String str = "[";
for(int i=0; i<arrayList.size(); i++){
  if(i == arrayList.size()-1){
      //Don't add comma at the end.
      str += arrayList.get(i);    
  }
  else{
      str += arrayList.get(i)+",";
  }
}
str += "]";
```

Comment: the output must be in this format  [1000000062,1000000095,1000000058]

Answer (score 1):

Please try this :

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   ArrayList<String> selectedId = new ArrayList<String>();

   if (infodata.get(position).isclicked) {
         infodata.get(position).isclicked = false;
   } else {
         infodata.get(position).isclicked = true;
   }

   for(int i=0;i<infodata.size();i++) {
      if (infodata.get(i).isclicked) {
          selectedId.add(data.get(i).getId());    
      }
   }
   System.out.println("Selected id are : "+selectedId.toArray());
}
```

Comment: selectedId.toArray() returns an object not an array

Comment: "Returns a new array containing all elements contained in this ArrayList"